# Finding overlapping sets

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, set-theory

I'm writing a [Digital Fountain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fountain_code) system in C#. Part of this system creates me sets of integers, I need to find the combinations of sets which create can leave me with a set of just one item. What's the fastest way to do this?

```
Set A: 1,2,3,4,5,6
Set B: 1,2,3,4,6
Set C: 1,2,3
Set D: 5,6

Solutions:
A - B => 5
A - (C + D) => 4
```

I don't need to find *all* combinations, just enough to find me as many unique numbers as possible. This may be possible to exploit to create a more efficient algorithm.

An important point that I forgot to mention:
I do not know, beforehand, how many sets there are, instead I add them one by one, and must determine each time if I have found every number I require. So the algorithm must be something which can be run in stages as new sets are added.

Nb. Solutions in C# get bonus marks ;)

Comment: In practice, how many sets/integers do you have ?

Comment: Are sets always sorted ?

Comment: @Loic: Probably a lot, that's highly variable though.

Comment: @Eric: No, these are pure unordered sets

Comment: @Martin: A lot, like in 10^3, 10^6, 10^12 ?

Comment: @Loic: Probably around 10^6, but really it could be a lot more in some circumstances

Comment: Also, what size of set should we expect on average? (or range of numbers in set)

Comment: @Nikita: The range will probably be up to about 10^5. The average size of the set is a variable which can be controlled to create the most efficient decoding algorithm, so you can pick that at will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think some nice solutions can be gained by some sort of modification of using greedy set cover (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem) algorithm.

[pseudocode]
so:

```
1. sort sets by size descending
2.
foreach set in sets do:
  uncovered = set.size
  while uncovered > 1
    current_set = the biggest set that covers no more than (uncovered - 1) and was not used before to cover set
    uncovered = uncovered - covered_by_set(set)
    collect current_set to some array
  end
end
```

**edit:**

- you can ommit foreach loop for last
  set
- this will bring you no more than one
  solution for each of sets (to fix
  this you can change problem directly
  into set cover problem and use greedy
  set cover), for example if you array
  [1,3,4], you need to find solution of
  SCV problem for all subsets of it
  that have size = 2: [1,3],
  [1,4], [3,4]. it will make problem
  much more complex
- another way that you may consider are
  evolution algorithms (representation
  here will be very simple, treat
  specified number as bit, fitness
  function should grow closer to 1),
  but this still don't solve problem of
  adding new set after calculations
  (maybe when you have best population
  from last problem, then after adding
  new set just add new place in
  chromosome)

Comment: That's a nice looking solution. But how well will it work with the constraint of constantly adding new sets (which I forgot to mention previously, sorry)?

Comment: this will be harder, you can do one step only for new set for new set (checking sets with smaller sizes) or do it for added set and each greater set (this will work slow if you will be adding sets often)

Comment: Just a note, I'm not ignoring this answer. I'll upvote sometime soon, I'm busy trying to implement a variation of this and seeing how fast it is.

Comment: The final algorithm I used to solve the problem eliminated the need for this altogether. Good answer though, thanks :)